# I am using Retrofit 2.0. I want to handle all types of network errors and exceptions

Tags: android, retrofit

**my application crashes when I have no internet connection : I am looking for a method that handles any exception form the retrofit instance like server is not found exception Timeout No internet connection**

RequestRepository : my repository which contain all my functions

```
class RequestRepository {
    /** suspend function to get the result of token request*/
    suspend fun getToken(userLoginModel: UserLoginModel): Response<TokenResponse> {
        return ApiService.APILogin.getToken(userLoginModel)
    }
```

ApiService : contain my Retofit instance

```
object ApiService {
    private var token: String = ""
    fun setToken(tk: String) {
        token = tk
    }

private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).addInterceptor { chain ->
        val chainRequest = chain.request()
        val requestBuilder = chainRequest.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("authorization", "Token $token")
            .method(chainRequest.method, chainRequest.body)
        val request = requestBuilder.build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }.build()

var gson = GsonBuilder()
    .setLenient()
    .create()
private val retrofit by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(LOGIN_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
}

val API: WebServicesApi by lazy {
    retrofit.create(WebServicesApi::class.java)

}
```

WebServicesApi  : my interface which contain my requests

```
interface WebServicesApi {

    /** get the token from the API*/
    @POST("user/login/")
    suspend fun getToken(@Body userLoginModel: UserLoginModel): Response<TokenResponse>
}
```

LoginViewModel : my viewModel class

```
class LoginViewModel(private val repository: RequestRepository) : ViewModel() {
    var tokenResponse: MutableLiveData<Response<TokenResponse>> = MutableLiveData()


    /** using coroutine in getToken function to get the token   */
    fun getToken(userLoginModel: UserLoginModel) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val tResponse = repository.getToken(userLoginModel)
            tokenResponse.postValue(tResponse)
            Log.d(TAG, "getToken: ${userLoginModel.password}")

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `Interceptor` for handle error like this:

```
class GlobalErrorInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        try {
            val response = chain.proceed(request)
            if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                val statusCode = response.code
                when (statusCode) {
                    //Your handle status code in here
                }
            }
            return response
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
           // You can replace my code with your exception handler code
            return Response.Builder().request(chain.request()).protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                .message("Can't connect!").code(500).body(
                    ResponseBody.create(
                        "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull(),
                        ""
                    )
                ).build()
        }
    }
}
```

And you must add this class to `OkHttpBuider`:

```
 val httpBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
 ......
 httpBuilder.addInterceptor(GlobalErrorInterceptor())
```